# plot and limit are not in agreement

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I am plotting the following function $\frac{\sqrt{t \text{$\omega_c $}}-\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{1}{t \text{$\omega_c $}}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t \text{$\omega_c$}}}\right)}{(t \text{$\omega_c$})^{3/2}}$ for $\omega_c=1$

```
 (Sqrt[t*\[Omega]c] - E^(1/(t*\[Omega]c))*Sqrt[Pi]*Erfc[1/Sqrt[t*\[Omega]c]])/(t*\[Omega]c)^(3/2)
```

and I am obtaining

[image]

where we clearly see that the function diverges as $t \rightarrow 0$.
What is interesting is that if I perform the limit through Mathematica for $t\rightarrow 0$ I obtain

[image]

which clearly disagrees with the graph. It is important to note that for $t\approx 10^{-3}$ the graph tends to the same correct limit, indicated by the blue line. Is there any way to increase the precision of the plot?

Comment: `Plot[..., WorkingPrecision -> 20]`